# jQuery, CSS - Shrink header image and stick to top when scrolled

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-position

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 300) {
    $(".tabs-row").addClass("stick-to-top");
    $(".tabs-wrapper ul").fadeOut();
    $(".stat-accordion").fadeOut();
    $(".profpic").addClass("profpic-to-top");
  } else {
    $(".tabs-row").removeClass("stick-to-top");
    $(".tabs-wrapper ul").fadeIn();
    $(".stat-accordion").fadeIn();
    $(".profpic").removeClass("profpic-to-top");
  }
});
```

```css
.profpic {
  position: absolute;
  top: -32px;
  width: 148px;
  height: auto;
  border: solid 4px #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.profpic.profpic-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 64px;
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shop-header">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="banner-img" src="img/banner.png">
    </a>
    <div class="banner-panels">
      <div class="banner-items-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="profpic" src="img/profpic.png">
        </a>
        <div class="panel-row-1">
          <div class="banner-title">
            <h1>Tas Kamera Square<span><img class="gold-merchant" src="img/goldmerchant.png"></span></h1>
            <p>Fast Response, Fast Order</p>
          </div>
          <div class="socmed">
            <span class="share-to">Bagikan ke: </span>
            <ul>
              <li class="facebook">
                <img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/facebook.svg">
              </li>
              <li class="twitter">
                <img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/twitter.svg">
              </li>
              <li class="google">
                <img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/google.svg">
              </li>
              <li class="blogger">
                <img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/blogger.svg">
              </li>
              <li class="link green-btn">
                <img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/link.svg">
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-row-2">
          <div class="shop-info-top">
            <ul>
              <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/truck.svg"></span>13 jam</li>
              <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/clock.svg"></span>20 menit yang lalu</li>
              <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/location.svg"></span>Kota Semarang</li>
              <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/home.svg"></span>1 Toko Fisik</li>
              <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/open.svg"></span>November 2013</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-row-3">
          <div class="update">
            <span><img class="svg quotation" src="img/svg/quotation-mark.svg">
                                TAS KAMERA READY Resellers Dropshippers are welcome 
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-panel">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="stat-panel-top"><img class="speedometer" src="img/speed.png"></div>
                                        <p>Kecepatan Toko</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="stat-panel-top"><img class="medal" src="img/gold-medal-3.png"></div>
                                        <p>Reputasi</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="stat-panel-top"><span class="stat-sold"><a href="#">139rb</a></span>
          </div>
          <p>Produk Terjual</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="stat-panel-top"><span class="stat-faved"><a href="#">145rb</a></span>
            </div>
            <p>Favorit</p>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make a page with header (profile banner and profile picture) Facebook style. I want to make the profile pic shrink and stick to top (to be new navigation bar) when I scroll past the header. I put the profile picture in `position: absolute` initially, and added the class like this

```
.profpic {
    position: absolute;
    top: -32px;
    width: 148px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 4px #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.profpic.profpic-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px;
    width: 32px;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

And this is the jQuery I use (the banner height is 300px for example)

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 300) {
        $(".tabs-row").addClass("stick-to-top");
        $(".tabs-wrapper ul").fadeOut();
        $(".stat-accordion").fadeOut();
        $(".profpic").addClass("profpic-to-top");
    }
    else {
        $(".tabs-row").removeClass("stick-to-top");
        $(".tabs-wrapper ul").fadeIn();
        $(".stat-accordion").fadeIn();
        $(".profpic").removeClass("profpic-to-top");        
    }
});
```

These codes only make my profile picture shrink to left-bottom (supposedly it should be go to the top because it is for navbar), and it still scrolled along with the page.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you very much! :)

**edit** The HTML

```
<div class="shop-header">
            <div class="banner-wrapper">
                <a href="#"><img class="banner-img" src="img/banner.png"></a>
                <div class="banner-panels">
                    <div class="banner-items-container">
                        <a href="#"><img class="profpic" src="img/profpic.png"></a>
                        <div class="panel-row-1">
                            <div class="banner-title">
                                <h1>Tas Kamera Square<span><img class="gold-merchant" src="img/goldmerchant.png"></span></h1>
                                <p>Fast Response, Fast Order</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="socmed">
                                <span class="share-to">Bagikan ke: </span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="facebook"><img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/facebook.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="twitter"><img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/twitter.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="google"><img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/google.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="blogger"><img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/blogger.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link green-btn"><img class="svg socmed-logo" src="img/svg/link.svg"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-row-2">
                            <div class="shop-info-top">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/truck.svg"></span>13 jam</li>
                                    <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/clock.svg"></span>20 menit yang lalu</li>
                                    <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/location.svg"></span>Kota Semarang</li>
                                    <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/home.svg"></span>1 Toko Fisik</li>
                                    <li><span><img class="svg info-img" src="img/svg/open.svg"></span>November 2013</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>                          
                    <div class="panel-row-3">
                        <div class="update">
                            <span><img class="svg quotation" src="img/svg/quotation-mark.svg">
                                TAS KAMERA READY Resellers Dropshippers are welcome 
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-panel">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="stat-panel-top"><img class="speedometer" src="img/speed.png"></div>
                                        <p>Kecepatan Toko</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="stat-panel-top"><img class="medal" src="img/gold-medal-3.png"></div>
                                        <p>Reputasi</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="stat-panel-top"><span class="stat-sold"><a href="#">139rb</a></span></div>
                                        <p>Produk Terjual</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="stat-panel-top"><span class="stat-faved"><a href="#">145rb</a></span></div>
                                        <p>Favorit</p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add some relative `html` too?

Comment: Hi, I'm bit confused with your requirement here. Do you want the image to appear throughout the page or you want it to shrink it and stay inside the navbar ?

Comment: try this one

`$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function () {
  $(".profpic").toggleClass('profpic-to-top', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
});`

Comment: @Help The latter it is. Actually it will looks like positioned in `tabs-row` because it is the new navbar (eventhough it is okay if the profpic floated on top of the new navbar just like that). I edit the jQuery to be more detailed :)

Comment: **[Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3fv6Lozf/)**?

Comment: @Rosiana If we are to provide exact solution, then you need to help us creating the exact scenario, either by `fiddle` or through snippet.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Well I'm sorry I'm new... Yeah that is what I want to achieve, but the profpic is in the banner (just like Facebook). What did you change in my code? Could you please make this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just have to change `top` property of `.profpic.profpic-to-top` CSS to `0px`. Here is the Updated Code.

```
.profpic.profpic-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; /*This change here*/
    width: 32px;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

**[Here's the DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3fv6Lozf/1/)**

---

**Update**

After looking at your Site code, I observed that you have `navbar` fixed, whose `z-index` is some `9999` and the `profpic` was going under it. Because of the hierarchy, the `.profpic` element is placed, no matter what you do, it used to go under `fixed navbar`. One thing I would suggest here is, keep a copy of your `profpic` element inside `navbar`, `hidden` initially and when you `scroll` document, hide original `image` and display the one present inside `navbar` and vice versa. The updated `HTML` for `.navbar` would be:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="profpic profpic-to-top" src="img/profpic.png" style="display: none;">
  </a>
  <div class="nav-menu-wrapper">
     <!--Other Stuffs-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Now on `scroll` event, toggle visibility between these 2 elements.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 300) {
        $(".navbar .profpic").show(200); //show navbar prof pic
        $(".banner-items-container .profpic").addClass("profpic-to-top").hide(200);
        //to keep effect of shrinking we will still have addClass and then hide
    }
    else {
        $(".navbar .profpic").hide(200);
        $(".banner-items-container .profpic").show(200).removeClass("profpic-to-top");
        //vice versa of above.
    }
});
```

Comment: In my code it still scrolled. I don't know what I did wrong. But thank you :)

Comment: @Rosiana Could you somehow `visualize` me of the same?

Comment: If you have time you can take a look at my work [here it is](https://rosiana.github.io/tp/shop-2.html) . The picture still scrolled. I thank you very much for your help sir :)

Comment: Omg it works! I need to remember this behavior from now on. Thank you very much for your time kind Sir :))

Comment: Please stop with **"Sir"**. You can address me with my name.. :) Happy Coding.. :)